# Combining OpenGL ES template and Utility template

Tags: iphone

I would like to have an OpenGL view with an utility application.

What I do:
I create an OpenGL ES application template and a Utility Application template.
I copy the files EAGLView.m and h, and the five ES*renderer.* files from the Opengl project to the utility project.

I copy these lines from the OpenGl project to the Utility project: (in utilityAppDelegate.m)

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
...
[glView startAnimation];
}

- (void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
[glView stopAnimation];
}

- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
[glView startAnimation];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
[glView stopAnimation];
}

- (void)dealloc {
...
 [glView release];
...
}
```

And in the utilityAppDelegate.h I add:

```
@class EAGLView;
EAGLView *glView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet EAGLView *glView;
```

I go to the view's identity inspector, and change the class identity to EAGLview.

I open the mainview.xib and mainwindow.xib and drag the app_delegate from the mainwindow.xib, to be able to connect the glView outlet to the view.
(Don't know if this is the way to do it, but that's the only way I could connect the glView variable to the view)

When I build and run, the multi colored square show up on the screen, but it does not animate!

When I debug, the glView variable is 0 in applicationDidFinishLaunching, and the startAnimation is not called. I suspect this has something to to with the way the outlet is connected to the view? Probably not connected. :-)
The mistake is probably obvious, but I have only been 5 weeks on this platform.

What is missing? What have I done wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution in another forum:
http://iphonedevbook.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=3192&sid=9cf79468b81a8fd6c9d9020958d33388

Basically, just add the glView outlet to the MainViewController instead of the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've provided enough information to tell exactly what's going wrong in your case.  However, I'd suggest that you look at the source code for my iPhone application [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules).

While it is a little more complex, the application is based on those two templates.  It uses an OpenGL ES main view (where a 3-D molecular rendering is presented), and a table view / navigation controller on the flipside (for switching molecular structures,  examining their properties, and downloading new ones).  You could review that example to see what you might be doing wrong, or even just replace my rendering and view code with your own.

Comment: Thanks, but your Molecules example is a little too complicated for me, who is just starting out with the iPhone SDK.

Comment: You may want to start with smaller projects before tackling mixing two templates.